# Discord 'Embed' object has no attribute '_files'

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

Tryna send an embed message on the new discord.py 2.0 and isn't working for me.

```
@Bot.command()
async def agent(ctx):
    list = ["Neon", "Reyna"]
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Agent Picker")
    emb.set_footer(text=f"Used by: {ctx.author.name}")
    emb.add_field(name=f"Agent:", value=f"{random.choice(list)}")
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

This is the error im getting after running the command, All my embed commands have stopped working and ive got no idea's to why.

```
Ignoring exception in command agent: 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 173, in wrapped ret = 
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/abc.py", line 1564, 
in send if embed._files: AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute '_files'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on the new discord.py 2.0

The error message suggests you're using **disnake**, **not discord.py 2.0**.

```
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/abc.py", line 1564, 
#                                                          ^^^^^^^
```

You're mixing different versions/forks of the library here, which will lead to bugs like this.

Assuming this isn't on purpose, uninstall **every** single discord-related library (`disnake`, `discord-components`, etc) and reinstall ONLY `discord.py`. Installing `disnake` broke your `discord.py` installation, so you have to get a clean reinstall without all the other libraries messing with it.

Also, make sure you replace every disnake-related import with a discord.py-one. You can't pass disnake objects to discord.py & vice-versa.